# Adding items to list in Prolog relative to other items in the list

Tags: list, prolog

I am new to Prolog and hope this is a simple thing to do. I want to add an item somewhere in the list based on few facts relative to other items in the list. For example, "X service is started sometime after Y" but you know X is not the last service to be run. There are many of these little blurbs of information and eventually the list will figure out the order. Just for now I wanted to know how to input the item "After" or "Before" a certain other item. As a form of a rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course much depends on the structure of your program.

Let's say you have a database `service(ID, StartTime)`

```
:- dynamic service/2.
```

The initial list could be built at once using `setof(StartTime-ID, service(ID, StartTime), List)`, and an element could be added with

```
add_service([ST0-ID0|R], service(ID, ST), [ST-ID, ST0-ID0|R]) :-
   ST < ST0, !.
add_service([E|R], S, [E|T]) :-
   add_service(R, S, T).
add_service([], S, [S]).
```

Testing with this data

```
service(a, 10).
service(b, 5).
service(c, 20).

?- setof(StartTime-ID, service(ID, StartTime), List), add_service(List, service(z, 12), Updated).
List = [5-b, 10-a, 20-c],
Updated = [5-b, 10-a, 12-z, 20-c].
```